# How to use compass breakpoint with susy?

Tags: susy-compass, compass-sass

i'm new on using compas / susy and i'm building my grid with the mobile first approach.
after lot of reads, i don't understand how to use compass breakpoints ($mobile,$tablet,$desktop) with susy.
Actually i need to set my $container width:

```
  //*Réglage de la grille de Susy - approche mobile-first
$total-columns: 8;             // nombre de colonnes de la grille de base
$column-width: 4em;            // largeur de chaque colonnes
$gutter-width: 1em;            // taille de la gouttière entre colonnes
$grid-padding: $gutter-width;  // grid-padding equal to gutters

//Réglage du nombre de colonnes pour at-breakpoint() mixin 
// qui simplifie les media-queries
$mobile   : 4;
$tablet   : 10;
$desktop  : 14;
```

then for my container :

```
#general{
@include container;
@include susy-grid-background; 
     @include at-breakpoint($desktop) {
         @include ???
     }
 }
```

after for elements i think this could be:

```
#header{
    @include  @include span-columns(3);
    @include at-breakpoint($desktop) {
         @include span-columns(13, $desktop);
         @include prefix(3, $desktop);

}
```

thanks for help

EDIT1:
whith this code

```
#general{
    //Approche mobile-first,réglage pour mobile
    @include container;
    @include susy-grid-background;
    #header{}
    #header-inner{}
    #content-global{}
    #left-content{}
    #content-inner{}
    #right-content{}
    #footer{}
    @include at-breakpoint($desktop) {/*    //Dimensions pour les pc*/
           @include set-container-width;

        #header{@include span-columns($desktop,$desktop);}
        #header-inner{}
        #content-global{@include span-columns($desktop,$desktop);}
        #left-content{@include span-columns(2 alpha,$desktop);}
        #content-inner{@include span-columns(10,$desktop);}
        #right-content{@include span-columns(2 omega,$desktop);}
        #footer{@include span-columns($desktop,$desktop);}
     }
     @include at-breakpoint($tablet) {/*     //Dimensions pour les tablettes*/
            @include set-container-width;

         #header{}
         #header-inner{}
         #content-global{}
         #left-content{}
         #content-inner{}
         #right-content{}
         #footer{}
     }
}
```

firebug give me:

```
@media (min-width: 36.75em)
#general {
max-width: 49em; => applied
}
@media (min-width: 51.75em)
#general {
max-width: 69em;=> not applied
}
```

why my breakpoint isn't applied ? 
does exist a mixin or something like that to make images responsive (susy or compass)?

EDIT2: still testing and seem this work better but the container isn't centered as it was with your suggestion.but why ? i face to the basic container setting, and my columns settings doesn't override mobile-first setting too.

```
     #general{
                //Approche mobile-first,réglage pour mobile
                @include container;
                @include susy-grid-background;
                        @include at-breakpoint($desktop) {/*    //Dimensions pour les pc*/
                @include span-columns($desktop);
                #header{@include span-columns($desktop);}
#left-content{@include span-columns(2 alpha,$desktop);}...}
```

EDIT3: another test that seem better, i think my at-breakpoint are applied but the max width is still 49em instead of 69em..

```
     #general{
                //Approche mobile-first,réglage pour mobile
                @include container;
                @include susy-grid-background;
                        @include at-breakpoint($desktop) {/*    //Dimensions pour les pc*/
                 @include set-container-width($desktop);
                #header{@include span-columns($desktop);}
#left-content{@include span-columns(2 alpha,$desktop);}...}
```

at this point, i think that `@include set-container-width($desktop);` is better for the container width changing, and `@include span-columns($desktop);` for the elements nested in the container.

EDIT4(08/11/13)

```
#header {
     .headHaut {@include span-columns($mobile);
                .logoHead {  @include set-container-width;}
                .menuImg {  @include set-container-width;}
     }
     .headBas {@include span-columns($mobile);
               .site-slogan{@include span-columns($mobile);}
                    }                
@include at-breakpoint($desktop) {/*    //Dimensions pour les pc*/
 .headHaut {@include set-container-width;
                .logoHead { @include span-columns(3,$desktop);}
                .menuImg {  @include span-columns(7 omega,$desktop);}
     }
     .headBas {@include span-columns($desktop);
               .site-slogan{@include span-columns(7,$desktop);}
               } 
}
```

doesn't render the same as,with the same grid settings,

```
 #header {
         .headHaut {@include span-columns($mobile);
                    .logoHead {  @include set-container-width;}
                    .menuImg {  @include set-container-width;}
         }
         .headBas {@include span-columns($mobile);
                   .site-slogan{@include span-columns($mobile);}
                        }                
    @include at-breakpoint($desktop) {/*    //Dimensions pour les pc*/
#header{
     .headHaut {@include set-container-width;
                    .logoHead { @include span-columns(3,$desktop);}
                    .menuImg {  @include span-columns(7 omega,$desktop);}
         }
         .headBas {@include span-columns($desktop);
                   .site-slogan{@include span-columns(7,$desktop);}
                   } 
  }  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. `at-breakpoint` is actually part of Susy, and you have the right idea for using it. Anything nested inside the at-breakpoint mixin will take affect at the size you set. Put anything in there that you want to change at that size.

Your `#header` example will work great, but could be simplified it. `at-breakpoint` changes the default context for all nested items, meaning you don't need to pass `$desktop` to the children (it's now the default).

For the container, you have several options. The first is simply to repeat your call to `container` and `susy-grid-background` inside each breakpoint. That duplicates some output, so there are ways to simplify it, if you like:

```
// a shortcut for setting multiple containers
// - simplest version, but doesn't include changes to the grid background
#general { @include container($total-columns, $desktop); }

// more control, with optimal output
// - use set-container-width, because width is the only thing you need to change
// - you can add the grid background at each breakpoint as well
#general {
  @include container;
  @include at-breakpoint($desktop) {
    @include set-container-width;
  }
}
```

I often take a different approach entirely - setting my container to *only the largest* of my breakpoints, and letting it be completely fluid below that. But that depends a lot on your design.

Comment: glad i didn't wrong ;) but i got some questions : 
- i saw on the web that variables like $desktop or $tabler could be named differently as $large ..does exist a naming rule for that ?
- actually my at-breakpoint isn't aplly and i get this result in firebug (see edit original post) why ?

Comment: seem that my breakpoints are applied, but how to enlarge the width of my desktop breakpoint ? actually it's set on 49em but i would to have 60em..how can i do that ? thanks

Comment: yes i think i found the way..when i modify the $column-width: to 5em from 4em, the container move to 59em from 49em...simple things are often the last we find..

Comment: bad news, if i do a nested breakpoint into code, browser size render is different than unested code, see my edit in original

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble following all your edits. I'm not sure what the question is currently.

Comment: my last code is on edit 4, and i found that if i nested the code i mustn't add some mixin or other for the mobile first element,if not the breakpoint override doesn't work..

Comment: do i need to use <meta name="viewport"…> or something else, to get breakpoint work ? because, perhaps,  it's the source of this issue.

Comment: Actually, yes, you probably do for most phones. Without setting the viewport, phone default to 800px or so, and scale your site rather than using media-queries. Set width to device-width, and set initial-scale to 1. That's all you need.

Comment: thanks , since i added the meta `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />` , breakpoints seem to be better applied.great

Comment: i just start to setup values for the tablet breakpoint,and all gone away..the tablet breakpoint is applied to my desktop view (1920px large)...i go crazy with this grid that do what it want ! :(

Comment: hopefully, my breakpoints work good with this.but i don't understand why my desktop breakpoint isn't applied instead of the tablet one..

Comment: i just find this : http://www.zell-weekeat.com/a-complete-tutorial-to-susy-part-2/ , is it a good approach ?

Comment: to get back on a point , to enlarge a grid what's the best way ? only increase the `$column-width` or increase other variables ? does exist a tool to calculate the `$column-width` and others variables related to a px value , like if i want a value to 990px the tool tell me how the `$column-width` do match ? thanks

Comment: If you are using fluid/magic grids, you can just set the `$container-width`, and we'll adjust your columns to fit. That won't work with static grids, because it's a bad idea to build static grids based on an outer width. Depending on the width you would choose, and number of columns, we might end up with a decimal column-width, which is not good when you're working in pixels. For static grids: multiplying is much safer than dividing.